# Using regular expression with Java (some specific characters)

Tags: java, regex

I have this example:

```
String str = "HellMCo I fiCZMnd thBVMis site intZereVCsting";
String tags = "BCMVZ";
```

I need a regular expression that helps me to find every combination of **tags**. As you can see in **str** we find four variations. I don't know too much about regular expressions.

I'm starting to test with this pattern:

```
(\d{,1}[BCMVZ])
```

PD: I'm testing here http://regexpal.com/ but it doesn't work my pattern.

So my real question is, how can I detect any variation of any character from another string?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You're wanting to find any occurrence of one or more characters out of the `tags` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try someting like:

```
[BCMVZ]+
```

it find any tags combinations with this chars `BCMVZ`.

Comment: +1, but I got rid of the slightly confusing forward slashes. :)

Comment: I understand, I don't know how regex string pattern write exactly in java )

Comment: It is just a String :) `String regex = "[BCMVZ]+";` You might want to add brackets to create a group.

Comment: Well, I'm using Matcher and Pattern classes to replace those variations. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @MartijnCourteaux thanks for your help, and @Victor. I wonder if we can use regex to find in a string words that starts with "h" or "H" and/or contain "pep" in a single regex. I have this `(\b[hH])(pep)` but it doesn't work the second part.

Comment: Try: `^([hH]).*(pep).*`. However, consider using simpler methods like `String.startsWith` and `String.contains`.

Comment: Well @MartijnCourteaux I'm trying to focus on regular expresions to know other ways to do it, I really appreciate your help. Thanks.